Pullback by a diffeomorphism preserves flow

Let $M,N$ be differentiable manifolds and let $f:M\to N$ be a diffeomorphism. For each $X\in \mathfrak{X}(N)$, define $f^*(X):=df^{-1}\circ X\circ f$. Let $\varphi _t$ be the flow of $X$ and let $\psi _t$ be the flow of $f^*(X)$. Prove that $f\circ \psi _t=\varphi _t\circ f$.

So I have to prove that for all $t\in (-\varepsilon ,\varepsilon )$, for a sufficiently small $\varepsilon$, and for all $p\in M$ we have $(f\circ \psi _t)(p)=(\varphi _t\circ f)(p)$. If I let $\sigma _p$ be an integral curve for $f^*(X)$ starting at $p$ and $\gamma _{f(p)}$ be an integral curve for $X$ starting at $f(p)$ then $\sigma _p(0)=p$, $\sigma _p'(t)=f^*(X)_{\sigma _p(t)}$, $\gamma _{f(p)}(0)=f(p)$ and $\gamma _{f(p)}'(t)=X_{\gamma _{f(p)}(t)}$. I also get$$(f\circ \psi _t)(p)=f(\psi _t(p))=f(\sigma _p(t))=(f\circ \sigma _p)(t)$$and$$(\varphi _t\circ f)(p)=\varphi _t(f(p))=\gamma _{f(p)}(t).$$If I fix $p$ then I have to prove that $(f\circ \sigma _p)(t)=\gamma _{f(p)}(t)$ for all $t\in (-\varepsilon ,\varepsilon )$. Clearly$$(f\circ \sigma _p)(0)=f(\sigma _p(0))=f(p)=\gamma _{f(p)}(0),$$so I only need to prove that $(f\circ \sigma _p)'(t)=\gamma _{f(p)}'(t)$ for all $t\in (-\varepsilon ,\varepsilon )$, because then they will both be integral curves for $X$ starting at $p$.
However, I get\begin{align*}(f\circ \sigma _p)'(t_0) & =d(f\circ \sigma _p)_{t_0}\left (\left .\frac{d}{dt}\right |_{t_0}\right ) \\
& =\left (df_{\sigma _p(t_0)}\circ d(\sigma _p)_{t_0}\right )\left (\left .\frac{d}{dt}\right |_{t_0}\right ) \\
& =df_{\sigma _p(t_0)}\left (d(\sigma _p)_{t_0}\left (\left .\frac{d}{dt}\right |_{t_0}\right )\right ) \\
& =df_{\sigma _p(t_0)}(\sigma _p'(t_0)) \\
& =df_{\sigma _p(t_0)}f^*(X)_{\sigma _p(t_0)} \\
& =df_{\sigma _p(t_0)}\left (df^{-1}_{f(\sigma _p(t_0))}X_{f(\sigma _p(t_0))}\right ) \\
& =\left (df_{\sigma _p(t_0)}\circ df^{-1}_{f(\sigma _p(t_0))}\right )X_{f(\sigma _p(t_0))} \\
& =X_{f(\sigma _p(t_0))},
\end{align*}while clearly $\gamma _{f(p)}'(t_0)=X_{\gamma _{f(p)}(t_0)}$. So I end up having to prove $f(\sigma _p(t_0))=\gamma _{f(p)}(t_0)$ again!
How can I fix this?
EDIT
I don't really know if this is useful because the flow is still a bit confusing for me, but I have proved that $f^*$ preserves the Lie bracket, i.e. that $f^*([X,Y])=[f^*(X),f^*(Y)]$, and I think the Lie bracket is somehow related to the flow, but I'm not sure about it.

How exactly is $\mathfrak{X}(N)$ defined? Depending on the definition, I would expect that you should be able to prove this by applying the uniqueness clause of the existence and uniqueness theorem for solutions to ODEs.

Is this from Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by John M. Lee? Does $\mathfrak{X}(N)$ represent the space of vector fields over $N$?

$\mathfrak{X}(N)$ is the space of smooth vector fields over $N$. I don't know if this is exactly form Lee's book because it's part of the excercises my professor gave for the class (Lee's book is one of the recommended books, but I haven't found this particular problem there).

I tried to prove this by applying the existence and uniqueness theorem for solutions of ODEs, but the problemis that I couldn't prove that they satisfy the same ODE (when I tried that I ended with the computation showed in the question).

I think you are trying to more than you need to. You have shown that for an integral curve $c$ for $f^*X$ such that $c(0)=p$, the curve $f\circ c$ is an integral curve for $X$ and $(f\circ c)(0)=f(p)$. But by uniqueness of integral curves and the definition of the flow, the fact that $c$ is an integral curve starting at $x$ says that $c(t)=\psi_t(p)$ while the fact that $f\circ c$ is an integral curve starting at $f(p)$ says that $f(c(t))=\phi_t(f(p))$. Since you can apply this to maximal integral curves and $p$ and $t$ are arbitrary, this shows that $f\circ\psi_t=\phi_t\circ f$ whenever both sides are defined.
